# How to execute HibernateQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

Im moving to java from C#, this is my frist try at actually writting something and I'm trying to setup my data layer, but I think I'm missing something like DataContext in LINQ to SQL in .NET

Im trying to query database using Hibernate but it seems like I'm missing something, I downloaded Hibernate 4 and QueryDSL for type safe queries.

Next I connected to my postgreSQL database and generated DAO objects using Dali(I think? in menu I selected JPA enteties from tables), written queries that I need but I am unsure which object I have to execute my query on (something like connection manager or something?)

Im missing something here I think:

```
EmployeesRepository repo = new EmployeesRepository();
List<Employees> employees = repo.GetByName("Steve");
Employees s = employees.get(0);
String g = s.getName();
```

My entity repository:

```
public class EmployeesRepository {

    public List<Employees> GetByName(String ename)
    {
        HibernateQuery qry = createQuery(employees);
        qry.where(employees.name.like(ename));
        return qry.list(employees);
    }

    private HibernateQuery createQuery(QEmployees employee)
    {
        return new HibernateQuery().from(employee);
    }
}
```

Im getting:

**java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No session in detached Query available**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create/open a hibernate session before executing query.

Example:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

When you are done with query execution, you need to close.

```
session.close();
```

Here is [step by step example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/hibernate-tutorial-for-beginners).

Note: There may be a hibernate version mismatch between what you are using and the one described in above example, you may need to just tweek it.

Comment: Can you show me exaple on how to do that? Am I missing some files like some kind of configuration?

Comment: @user1010609: Provided link for an example, that should help you.

Comment: Thanks, seems good. I hope I won't have any issues since I generated my DAO little different then in tutorial.

Comment: The created session is then to be used in the HibernateQuery constructor : `new HibernateQuery(session)`

Comment: The dzone article doesn't exist anymore. Please could you update. Thanks.

Comment: @susenj updated with another link which provides comprehensive steps. Good luck!